# Get days of week by current week

Tags: c#

After searching through stack overflow, I cant seem to find a solution. I've put together a chart (Chart.js) and I need to grab days of the current week bind that to the chart and match any days date to one stored in my db thus brining back all data based on that date.

So if anyone could give me any pointers on fetching List from the current week, that would be awesome.

I hope this is clear enough please feel free to ask more questions. Sorry no code struggling to get started. For me DateTime is an absolute nightmare to work with.

Regards,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [`DayOfWeek`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.dayofweek%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property of `DateTime`:

```
new DateTime(2014,11,16).DayOfWeek
```

So... to deal with a list of dates, first, let's make a list of dates:

```
var startDate = DateTime.Today;
var endDate = startDate.AddDays(7);
//the number of days in our range of dates
var numDays = (int)((endDate - startDate).TotalDays); 
List<DateTime> myDates = Enumerable
           //creates an IEnumerable of ints from 0 to numDays
           .Range(0, numDays) 
           //now for each of those numbers (0..numDays), 
           //select startDate plus x number of days
           .Select(x => startDate.AddDays(x))
           //and make a list
           .ToList();
```

and get the days of the week:

```
List<string> myDaysOfWeek = myDates.Select(d => d.DayOfWeek.ToString()).ToList();
```

if you want the week to start on (say) the previous Monday, you could alter `startDate` as follows:

```
startDate = startDate
           .AddDays(-(((startDate.DayOfWeek - DayOfWeek.Monday) + 7) % 7));
```

This works because we can treat the enumeration values of [`enum DayOfWeek`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dayofweek%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as numbers, so we can subtract `Monday`(value 1) from `Sunday`(value 0), which gives -1... then we do a bit of a jiggle to wrap this value to `6` using modulo maths. If you subtract the resulting value (measured in days) from the start date, you end up on the previous Monday.

Comment: or `DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek` if you don't want to hard code it.

Comment: `DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek` might be slightly faster and more closely represents the hard coded version.

Comment: @spender outstanding answer! If you don't mind could you run me through the process of "Enumerable
           .Range(0, (int)((endDate - startDate).TotalDays))
           .Select(x => startDate.AddDays(x))" ? and also the redeclaring of the startDate variable? Just would very much like to understand the process. Again thank you for your quick response. Regards.

Comment: @TezWingfield : I put some inline comments to help you through what's happening and a bit of explanation about finding the previous Monday.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to know the days of the current week, you need to:

```
Get the current day
Convert it to an integer
Subtract that many days from the current date. That gives you the date for Sunday.
Create a list, starting with Sunday.
```

So:

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
var currentDay = now.DayOfWeek;
int days = (int)currentDay;
DateTime sunday = now.AddDays(-days);
var daysThisWeek = Enumerable.Range(0, 7)
    .Select(d => sunday.AddDays(d))
    .ToList();
```